# Visualize the paths and find shortest path(s) in 3D cube

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, matlab-figure, shortest-path

I have some problems about the visualization of the paths and find the shortest paths from top to bottom.

Here is my code:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

Porosity = .3;
m=20;
n=20;
o=20;

Nodes= ones(m,n,o);

HLines = zeros(m,n-1,o-1);
HLines(randperm(numel(HLines),floor(Porosity*m*(n-1)*(o-1))))=1;
HLines

VLines = zeros(m-1,n,o-1);
VLines(randperm(numel(VLines),floor(Porosity*(m-1)*n*(o-1))))=1;
VLines

PLines = zeros(m-1,n-1,o);
PLines(randperm(numel(PLines),floor(Porosity*(m-1)*(n-1)*o)))=1;
PLines

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n-1
        for k=1:o-1
        if HLines(i,j)==1;
            hold on
            x = [i i+1];
            y = [j j];
            z = [k k];
            plot3(x,y,z,'r','linewidth',2)
        end
        end
    end
end

for i=1:m-1
    for j=1:n
        for k=1:o-1
        if VLines(i,j)==1;
            hold on
            x = [i i];
            y = [j+1 j];
            z = [k k];
            plot3(x,y,z,'r','linewidth',2)
        end
        end
    end
end

   for i=1:m-1
      for j=1:n-1
          for k=1:o
          if PLines(i,j,k)==1;
              hold on
              x = [i i];
              y = [j j];
              z = [k+1 k];
              plot3(x,y,z,'r','linewidth',2)
          end
          end
      end
   end

   axis([0 m 0 n 0 o])
   view(30,45)
   set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 1500 1000])
   xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Z')
```

This code gives me the following figure which consists of a 3D cube and randomly distributed of `1` and `0`:

[image]

If there is `1` then keep going; if there is `0`, then stop.

I want to visualize all of the paths from top to bottom, and I want to choose the shortest path(s).